# Discord.js trying to get new post from instagram account with nightmare

Tags: node.js, post, discord.js, instagram, send

I'm trying to get the each new post from certain instagram account, so right after i can send link to that ig post to the discord channel. However i have no idea how to do this.. I found that nightmare should be able to do that, however i'm not able to figure out how I'm supposted to get data from the new post... All i managed to get is the title of the Instagram account.
Library: `https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare`

**Is it possible to accomplish this via NightMare or is there different option i could manage it?**

```
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })
const accountName = 'worldstar'

const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const config = require("./config.json");

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.on('ready', () => {
  Nightmare({ show: false })
      .goto(`https://www.instagram.com/${accountName}`)
      .evaluate(() => {
        return document.url;
      })
      .end()
      .then((url) => {
        console.log(url);
      })
})

client.login(config.token);
```

Log: `null`